# How to make LinearProgress Bar functionally

Tags: flutter

I would like to make my own LinearProgressBar because I  want to set it's max value and increment value.

For example:
*1.ProgressBar
(max value: 100, increment percent: 10)*

I also used [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package but it is not allowing to set max value.

How can I do that ?

Comment: It is more like you want slider without thumb.

Comment: Thanks, that's solved my problem exactyl. Nice trick!

Answer (score 0):

You could try, using AnimatedContainer to make the animation of "increasing" and "decreasing", the layout you would make by yourself and using arithmetic logic to make increasing operations and "setState" function to trigger the animation.

Take a look in [Flutter's AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)